# laravel error when explicit model binding on route group

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-5.6

I wrote this route group

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin/{store}',  'middleware' => ['auth', 'SetStoreId'], 'namespace' => 'Admin'], function (App\Models\Store $store) {

Route::get('/', 'DashboardController@index');

Route::resources([
    '/vocabulary' => 'VocabularyController',
    '/term' => 'TermController',
]);

});
```

and accessed this url

```
http://localhost/SyriaShop/public/admin/1/vocabulary
```

then I get this error message

```
Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Routing\Router::{closure}() must be an instance of App\Models\Store, instance of Illuminate\Routing\Router given, called in E:\wamp\www\SyriaShop\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php on line 390
```

although when I use this config (without model binding)

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin/{storeId}',  'middleware' => ['auth', 'SetStoreId'], 'namespace' => 'Admin'], function ($storeId)
```

everything work well!

Comment: the route group closure takes an instance of the router, not anything you define. the routes in that group would be taking the parameter in their method definitions currently.

Answer (score 1):

The closure passed to `Route::group` gets called with an instance of the router passed to it (you don't control this as you are not the caller).

The actions for these routes in this group would be taking this route parameter, `store`, in their definitions.

If you don't want all these controller methods to need to take this route parameter you can remove this parameter from the route. (In that recently created middleware would be a good place)

```
$request->route()->forgetParameter('store');
```

This should remove the need for these controller methods to take this route parameter and you are already dealing with this route parameter in your middleware.

Comment: I added the explicit binding Route::model('store', Store::class); to the RouteServiceProvider and changed the SetStoreId Middleware to URL::defaults(['store' => $request->store->id]); and seems to be working. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That kind of implicit Model binding will work if the primary key of your table is 'id', since your code looks good I think that most probably your table doesn't have the column 'id' as primary key.

If that is the case you can override it using the following function on your model:

```
public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'slug';
}
```

Hope that's the case!

Comment: I made the store model using the make:model command and the stores table has the column 'id' as primary key.